# MeteorJS: trouble with dates in autoform and simpleschema

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I use Simple Schema, Collection2 and Autoform.
For example my collection is:

```
experience = new SimpleSchema ({
    date: {
        type: Date,
        label: "From",
        autoform: {
            'formgroup-class': 'col-sm-4',
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "bootstrap-datetimepicker",
            }
        }       
    }
}
Profile = new SimpleSchema({
    experience: {
        type: [experience]
    }
});
```

Now with autoform I can add multiple experiences. The problem is when I set any date and press on the "plus" button to add another experience. Then the date from the last one is cleared.